# need to rewrite this perl function . as libperl UserAgent is blocked

Tags: perl, lwp

One of the hosts I deal with is blocking me from downloading images from their site. I have spoken to them and they have asked me to change the user-agent `libwww-perl/` to `Mozilla/5.0`. The image links are http and https.

I have tried various options like

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
$ua->ssl_opts( verify_hostnames => 0 );
```

But I can't get it to work with `getstore`. Would appreciate any help.

```
    sub storeimage {
  my $image = shift;
  if ($image =~ m#^https?://.+\/(.+\.)([a-z]+)$#i) {
    my $ext = $2;
    my $filename = "$1$2";
    if (exists $wantedfiles{$ext}) {
      my $savepath = $localwantedpath.$wantedfiles{$ext};
      if (!-f $savepath.$filename) {
        unless (is_success(getstore($image, $savepath.$filename))) {
          _warn("Couldn't download file $image to $savepath.");
          return '';
        }

    if ( $ext =~ /jpg|jpeg/oi ) {
      system("mogrify -resize '800>' -quality 70 $savepath$filename");

      #mogrify -resize 800x800  -quality 70 -format jpg $imageloc
    }

      }
      return $wantedfiles{$ext}.$filename;

    }
  }
  return '';
}
```

Comment: i have tried this  my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new( ssl_opts => { verify_hostname => 1 } );
$ua->agent('Mozilla/5.0');  what i cant figure out is how do is save the image  to specified folder like getstore . from what i have read i cant use getstore with LWP::UserAgent.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why you're messing around with SSL options. Hostname verification has nothing to do with HTTP headers.

What you need is something like

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(agent => 'Mozilla/5.0');
```

to set the [`agent`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent#agent) attribute.

To replicate the [`getstore`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Simple#getstore) function (from [`LWP::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Simple)) with your `$ua` object, you need to do something like this:

```
unless ($ua->request(HTTP::Request->new('GET' => $image), $savepath.$filename)->is_success) {
    ...
}
```

See the [`request`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent#request) method.

Or maybe consider using [`mirror`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent#mirror):

```
$ua->mirror($your_url, $your_filename)
```

It behaves a bit differently, though.

Answer (score 4):

[LWP::Simple has a package variable](https://metacpan.org/source/OALDERS/libwww-perl-6.29/lib/LWP/Simple.pm#L28) with the user agent.

You can use that to change your agent string and still use `getstore`.

```
use LWP::Simple;

$LWP::Simple::ua->agent("Mozilla...");
getstore($url, $file);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new( agent => 'Mozilla/5.0' );
```

Comment: i have tried this  my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new( ssl_opts => { verify_hostname => 1 } );
$ua->agent('Mozilla/5.0');  what i cant figure out is how do is save the image  to specified folder like getstore . from what i have read i cant use getstore with LWP::UserAgent.